# Best Practice XML Request Builder in Java

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am developing a restful web service in Java. One of my service needs to call a SOAP service and for this I need to build an XML request. My question is that "I want to build that xml file in a seperate helper class, is this a convenient way to do? " I am using Spring for MVC, is there any advantages of it here that I can implement?

Example pseucode;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/menu")
public class MenuController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody JSONObject userInfo){
//Here I need to make a Soap call to retrieve some information
 MyXMLBuilder myXMLBuilder = new MyXMLBuilder(); 
 String soapRequest = myXMLBuilder.build();
}}
```

and here the helper class;

```
public class MyXMLBuilder(){
public String build(){
//xml build implementation 
}}
```

Comment: What should the ``build()`` method do ? Serialize some objets to XML ?

Comment: yes, exactly serializing objects to xml.

Comment: Your objects are annotated ?

Comment: Not annotated. I'm creating them from another service call.

Comment: You should annotate them, at least with @XmlRootElement... The you can use Marshaller to serialize to a StringOutputStream... Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, to consume a SOAP WebService, you will create the required stubs with the `wsimport` tool, which is within your Java SDK in the /bin folder.

Within your favourite terminal, switch to your desired folder for the stubs to be created in and type:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://example.com/myservice?wsdl
```

You can then use the Service Stubs like this

```
MyServiceImplService myService = new MyServiceImplService();
MyService port = myService.getMyServiceImplPort();

port.yourFunction(param1, param2);
```